# Is standard error the same as the "standard deviation of group means"?

Tags: standard-error

I have an example code in python to make the question more clear. I have data from different groups (person1, person2, and person3) and multiple measurements for each group.

I want to report statistics that describe all people. I find that the mean of the group means to be intuitive along with the standard deviation of the group means. It's unclear to me if what I'm calculating is the standard error. My confusion is from the typical formula of SE which includes a sqrt, but my impression is that the formula with the sqrt is used to estimate the SE if I only had measurements from one person (in this case).

Please let me know if my understanding is correct.

```
group_names = ['person1', 'person1', 'person1', 'person2', 'person2', 'person3', 'person3', 'person3']
numbers = [5, 8, 3, 6, 3, 5, 6, 9]

unique_group_names = np.unique(group_names)
group_means = []

for group_name in unique_group_names:
    print(group_name)
    numbers_within_group = [numbers[i] for i in range(len(unique_group_names)) if unique_group_names[i] == group_name]
    group_means.append(np.mean(numbers_within_group))

group_means = np.array(group_means)
overall_mean = np.mean(group_means)
standard_error = np.std(group_means) 

mean, std_err = overall_mean, standard_error
print(group_means)
print("Mean of group means:", mean)
print("Standard Error:", std_err)
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard error is sometimes called "the standard error of the mean"   you are calculating the standard deviation on a set of values that happen to be means of other sets of values.  You can calculate a standard error for this "mean of means" by dividing by the square root of the sample size

There is a connection here where iirc the SE is an estimate of the standard SD of repeated estimates (means) of the same quantity.  That may be what you are thinking of

Comment: Would the sample size in this case be 3? Or would it the total number of measurements across the full group? My confusion comes also from this video which seems to claim that the standard error = standard deviations of means: https://youtu.be/XNgt7F6FqDU?feature=shared&t=357

Comment: Yes, is should be 3.   I didn't watch the video , but they are probably emphasizing the conceptual underpinnings, not the practical application.